# Polymer elements: Fire event from child element to parent, then push values into array attribute

Tags: polymer

I've made this custom element (request-form), which contains a serie of elements (custom-inputs). request-form has a formvalues attribute, which is an array.

My goal is every time a custom-input value is changed, its new value should be pushed into the request form-array.

```
<polymer-element name="request-form" attributes="isSearch formvalues">
<template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <div layout vertical>
        <custom-core-input 
            columnId="12345678-1234-1234-123456789123"
            validation="^[0-9]*$" 
            inputRequired
            on-inputcommited="{{getinput}}">
        </custom-core-input>
        [... some more custom-core-inputs ...]
    </div>        
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        created: function () {
            this.formvalues = [];
        },
        getinput: function (e, detail, sender) {
            this.formvalues.push(detail.columnid + "|" + detail.inputval);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is the code  for when the value on the input field (id="custominput") in my custom-input element changes.

```
inputCommited: function () {
            this.$.decorator.isInvalid = !this.$.custominput.validity.valid;
            if (this.$.custominput.validity.valid) {
                var inputval = this.$.custominput.value;
                this.fire('inputcommited', { inputval: inputval, columnid: this.columnId });
            }
        }
```

Changing the value of an input does trigger this function, checks its valitidy and all, but never fires the parent element getinput function.

What I want, in the end, is to have an string array such as {"columnid1|value1", "columnid2|value2", [...]}

**EDIT**

After inserting a couple of alerts around I can positively state that the inputCommited in the child element works perfectly, and it runs all the code, before and after the 'this.fire(...)' statement.

Never the code in getinput though

**EDIT**

Well, this is a working example of what I'm trying to do, taken from the polymer example/tutorial shown on their webpage.

First, there's this post-card element, with two icons in it:

```
<polymer-element name="post-card">
   <template>
      <style>
      [...]
      </style>
      [...]
      <core-icon-button
          id="favicon"
          icon="favorite"
          on-tap="{{favoriteTapped}}">
      </core-icon-button>

      <core-icon-button
          id="banicon"
          icon="remove-circle"
          on-tap="{{bannedTapped}}">
      </core-icon-button>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
      publish: {
          favorite: {
              value: false,
              reflect: true
          },
          banned: {
              value: false,
              reflect: true
          }
      },
      favoriteTapped: function (event, detail, sender) {
          this.favorite = !this.favorite;
          this.banned = false;
          this.fire('favorite-tap');
      },
      bannedTapped: function (event, detail, sender) {
          this.banned = !this.banned;
          this.favorite = false;
          this.fire('banned-tap');
      }
  });
 </script>
 </polymer-element>
```

As you can see, whenever one of the two icons is tapped, the code tells it to fire and event, banned-tap or favorite-tap

Now, this is the parent element, post-list:

```
<polymer-element name="post-list" attributes="show">
 <template>
 <style>
 [...]
 </style>

<post-service id="service" posts="{{posts}}"></post-service>

<div layout vertical center>
  <template repeat="{{post in posts}}">
    <post-card
      favorite="{{post.favorite}}"          
      on-favorite-tap="{{handleFavorite}}" 
      banned="{{post.banned}}"
      on-banned-tap="{{handleBanned}}">
      [...]
    </post-card>
  </template>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
      handleFavorite: function (event, detail, sender) {
          var post = sender.templateInstance.model.post;
          this.$.service.setFavorite(post.uid, post.favorite);
      },
      handleBanned: function (event, detail, sender) {
          var post = sender.templateInstance.model.post;
          this.$.service.setBanned(post.uid, post.banned);
      }
  });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Both banned-tap and favorite-tap fire the parent event, and just as I want it, setting an `on-whatever="{{dosomething}}"`

Comment: I cannot find documentation for 'inputcommited' event?! Have you tried using 'change' event, as: on-change="{{getinput}}" ?

Comment: hmm lets see, as I understand it: my input has the event on-change, which triggers the inputCommited thing (second code snipet). So im telling the input that, once inputCommited has been fire, if its valid, then it has to fire 'inputcommited' on its parent. The parent is request form (first code snipet), which as you can see adds 'on-inputcommited' to the input, telling it to fire its own function (aka, getinput). Maybe I misunderstood the whole thing, but I think that is how it works ._.

Comment: To simplify it: I didn't put here the custom-core-input code but it has an event on-change in it. The on-change fires inputCommited (this IS working), checks if the input value is valid (this is also working), then tells if to fire inputcommited(all in lowercaps), which should be recognized at request-form(the parent) and fire getinput. Something is not working in the communication between the child and the parent, but the on-change event is firing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Another way to catch custom event from the child element is to do it in the prototype of the parent:
[[1]](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#fire), [[2]](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#events)

```
ready: function() {

        //select the custom-core-input(but first add this id attribute to it)
        var custom_core_input = this.$.id_custom_core_input;

         //wait for the event to fire
        this.addEventListener('inputCommited', function(e) {

        //Here comes inputCommited function code:

  });



<custom-core-input 
            columnId="12345678-1234-1234-123456789123"
            validation="^[0-9]*$" 
            inputRequired
            id="id_custom_core_input">
</custom-core-input>
```

Comment: The thing is, every custom-core-input is added dynamically, id doesn't make sense to me to put an id for everyone of them. Also, I know polymer can do something like I was trying. I'm updating my question with a working (simpler) example of what I'm trying to achieve. If I don't achieve that I guess I could work with your solution, but I'd prefer the other way.

Comment: Now I see your point, I'll edit my answer as 'another way to catch custom event'.

Comment: Your way its fine, but I think the way I'm trying is better for repeated templates, since you can handle all the events at once. Still can't make it work this way, though. If you see something different between the working code and mine please let me know.